# Why is my laravel 8 custom guard login always return false?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

> **This is the config/auth.php**

I have edited the auth the student provider

```
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords
        ' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
        'student' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'students',
        ],

       
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
        'students' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Student::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
        'students' => [
            'provider' => 'students',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 15,
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Confirmation Timeout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
    | times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
    | confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
    |
    */

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

> **this is my student model**
> i have edited the student model using the user model as base

```
 <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Student extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;
    protected $guard = 'student';


    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'birthdate',
        'Course',
        'Year',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

> **This is my Student LoginController**
> My login controller return the login form and below is the login attempt that always return false so it always redirect me back to the login page.

```
  <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    // use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController ;
    // use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
    
    
    class Student_loginController extends Controller
    {
        // public function __construct()
        //     {
        //         $this->middleware('guest:student')->except('logout');
               
            
        //     }
    
        public function index(){
    
            return view('auth.student_login');
        }
    
        public function login(Request $request){
           
            $this->validate($request,
            [
                'email' => 'required|email',
                'password' => 'required',
            ]);
          
    
        
            if(Auth::guard('student')->attempt($request->only('email','password'))){
                
                return redirect()->back()->with('failed',' student not successfully logged in');
                
            }
            return redirect('student_dashboard')->with('success','student login');
           
            
    
            
           
             
        }
    }
```

> **this is my route**

```
 <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\RegistrationController;
use App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController;
use App\Http\Controllers\LoginController;
use App\Http\Controllers\LogoutController;
use App\Http\Controllers\WelcomeController;
use App\Http\Controllers\StudentController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Student_loginController;
use App\Http\Controllers\student_dashController;





/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/



Route::get('/',[WelcomeController::class, 'index'])->name('welcome');
Route::get('register',[RegistrationController::class, 'index'])->name('register');
Route::get('dashboard',[DashboardController::class, 'index'])
->name('dashboard')
->middleware('auth');

Route::get('student_dashboard',[student_dashController::class, 'index'])
->name('student_dashboard');

Route::get('login',[LoginController::class, 'index'])
->name('login')
->middleware('guest');

Route::get('logout',[LogoutController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');
Route::get('student_login',[Student_loginController::class, 'index'])->name('student_login');
Route::get('student',[StudentController::class, 'index'])->name('student')->middleware('auth');;
Route::get('student/{student_ID}', [StudentController::class, 'show'])->name('student.showstudent')->middleware('auth');;


Route::post('register',[RegistrationController::class, 'store'])->name('register.store');
Route::post('store_student', [RegistrationController::class, 'store_student'])->name('store_student')->middleware('auth');
Route::post('student_login',[Student_loginController::class, 'login'])->name('student_login.login');
Route::post('login',[LoginController::class, 'login'])->name('login.login');
Route::post('student',[StudentController::class, 'store'])->name('student.store')->middleware('auth');;


Route::delete('student/{student_ID}',[StudentController::class, 'destroy'])->name('student.destroy')->middleware('auth');;
Route::put('showstudent/{student_ID}',[StudentController::class, 'edit'])->name('showstudent.edit')->middleware('auth');;




// Route::get('/', function () {
//     return view('welcome');
// });
```

Comment: Not sure if this could be the issue but In `auth.php` there is a carriage return in the string  `'passwords
        ' => 'users',`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Auth::guard('student')->attempt($request->only('email','password'))){
  return redirect()->back()->with('failed',' student not successfully logged in');}
```

Your are redirecting back with a failed message when login is true. You have redirect back with a failed message when login is fail. You have to write the logic like this.

```
if(!Auth::guard('student')->attempt($request->only('email','password'))){
  return redirect()->back()->with('failed',' student not successfully logged in');}
```

Last you have to protect student_dashboard route with middleware auth with its guard
auth:student

```
Route::middleware('auth:student')->group(function(){
Route::get('student_dashboard',[student_dashController::class, 'index'])
 ->name('student_dashboard');}
```

or return the middleware in your dashboard controller contsructor method like this

```
 public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:student');
}
```